# limit of square root function $\sqrt{x-10}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Evaluation of limits

$(a)\; \lim\limits_{x\to 10^{-}}\sqrt{x^2-100}$

$(b)\; \lim\limits_{x\to 7}\sqrt{x-10}$

$(a)$
Put $x=10-h$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 10^{-}}=\lim_{h\to 0}$

Where $h=0.0000000000001$

$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\sqrt{100+h^2-20h-100}=\sqrt{h}\sqrt{h-20}=0$

$(b)$

Put $\lim\limits_{x\to 7}\sqrt{x-10}=\sqrt{-3}=\sqrt{3}i$

Can anyone please tell me about my solution.

I have checked in Wolframalpha, it answers as $0$ and $\sqrt{3}i$

But I have seems that something wrong in $(a)$ and $(b)$ solution which I have given because of function domain.

For $1$ st $x\geq 10$ and for second $x\geq 10$

Thanks.

Comment: You should tell us if complex numbers are allowed. What course is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have pretty easy situation, because the limit is a value of function at given point (assuming that your domain is e.g. $\mathbb{C}$).
$(a)\; \lim_{x\rightarrow 10^{-}}\sqrt{x^2-100}=\sqrt{10^2-100}=\sqrt{0}=0$,
$(b)\; \lim_{x\rightarrow 7}\sqrt{x-10}=\sqrt{7-10}=\sqrt{-3}=\sqrt{3}i$.

You don't have to do nothing more than that.

*Alternatively for second problem*

Let $x:=7+h$, $h\rightarrow 0$. Then
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 7}\sqrt{x-10}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\sqrt{7+h-10}$$
which gives us the same result as above.

Comment: Thanks so much Novice. I have a doubt. So there is no role for domain Here and also is real valued limit has Imaginary value.plesse clearfy me. Thanks

Comment: I advise you to use my method which is more clear. The fact if these limits exist depends on your definition of domain. If it is bigger than normally evaluated (I mean standard domain for square roots) than we can evaluate the limit at every point. I do not know how your domain defined is.

Answer (score 2):

If you are considering $\sqrt{x^2-100}$ and $\sqrt{x-10}$ as functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$, then these limits don't exist because the functions are undefined for $x<10$.

And you can't consider them as functions from $\Bbb C$ to $\Bbb C$, because the square root function is not unambiguously defined over $\Bbb C$.

So the only context that makes sense is if they are considered as functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb C$, which is rather an unlikely interpretation.

So I would say the question is badly posed.